# How to allow join culling big query view?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to ensure when a view is used in google big query joins to table where a columns is not used is culled/excluded.

eg.

if the view is

```
Select  _fact.A
, _Dim.B
from _fact
inner join _dim
on _fact.dim_sk = _dim.Dim_sk
```

and I query

```
Select _fact.A 
from _view
```

It will ignore the `join` in the `_dim`

In  SQL Server if you create Foregin Key relationship it will do this.

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery does not have the concept of primary keys, so there is no way for it to preform such an optimization; it does not know in advance that all keys in `_dim` are unique. You could create a view of this form, however:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  A,
  (SELECT B FROM _dim
   WHERE _dim.dim_sk = _fact.dim_sk) AS B
FROM _fact;
```

When you select only `A` from this view, the query should not end up scanning any columns from `_dim`. You will need to ensure that there are no duplicate values of `dim_sk` in either table or else you will get an error that the scalar subquery produced more than one element.

Comment: just to clarify for other users - such view will work only if all `dim_sk` are unique in `_dim`